# Issue with hiding text on page before it appears onScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good evening,
I have a problem with hiding text on page when it loads, it should appear after I scroll down the page. But it's visible, when I reach the set point, it disappears and immediately appears again. And when I scroll to top again, then it finally disappears.
When I try to hide it with `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;`, it doesn't even appear.
What should I change in the code?
Thanks for your help!

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var pxFromBottom = 350;

  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - pxFromBottom) {
    $('.scroll-btn').fadeIn('slow')  
  } else {
    $('.scroll-btn').fadeOut('slow');     
  }

});
```

CSS:

```
html { height:2000px; background-color: #666; }
```

HTML:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top: 120%;" class="scroll-btn"> my content to show </div>
```

Comment: @H Sturma it'd easier to help you with a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you are scrolling down its when your code first hides the div, it doesnt 'fadein' and then 'fadeout'.
Just fades out.
The fix this,

add to the div style

```
display:none;
```

this way you wont be able to see div when scorlling down.

But this thing only fixes one problem.

Your div is placed at 120% of the viewport height. So if the viewport height is 1080px, the div will have top 1296px.

But in your js code, you check

```
if $(window).scrolltop + $(window).height > $(document).height() - pxFromBottom)
```

So by the time the div get displayed you cant see it because it was already scrolled by.
But its still get the fadeIn, so when you scroll back up you can see it before its get fadeOut agian.

you should change your if stament to this:

```
if (($(window).scrollTop()) > ($(window).height() - pxFromBottom))
```

This way you check if the current scroll, is bigger the viewport height - pxFromBottom. 
And once you scroll down you will the div fades in.

**Fiddle** - https://fiddle.jshell.net/jgthb6m2/5/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your issue is, but if the text needs to be hidden on load, perhaps do the following:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('.scroll-btn').hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the calculation. The below code display the text, when the scroll top reaches the text. I assume that when you scroll to the text it should appears and when you scroll to the top again the text should disappears.

```
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('.scroll-btn').position('top')) {
    $('.scroll-btn').fadeIn('slow');
    console.log('fade in');
  } else {
   $('.scroll-btn').fadeOut('slow'); 
    console.log('fade out');
  }
```